# NPM chown does not work as advertised

Tags: chown, npm

This is supposedly supposed to work

```
 sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

according to this article

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

but I have to break it up into these, because it won't work:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/lib/node_modules
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/bin
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/share
```

does anyone know why the suggested command does not work?

Comment: What exactly is it that "doesn't work"?  What happens when you do it?

Comment: Which shell are you using? Why is there a `RUN` at the beginning in the second form? Run `set -x` before you execute the command and edit your question to add the output. What is the output of `echo ba{r,z}`?